# How to make TestNG continue test execution on an exception?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, pageobjects

When i get an exception, the test run immediately ends, and any following test validations are skipped. I would like to catch the exception, handle it, then continue the workflow.

In the below example, If `objPage.Method1();` throws an exception, the entire `@Test` immediately ends. I would like the `catch` to execute, then move on to `objPage.Method2()`.

```
@Test (enabled=true)
public void MyClientsFunctions() throws Exception {
    ExtentTest t = ReportFactory.getTest();
    try {

        Login objPage = new PageObject(driver);

        //this method throws exception
        objPage.Method1();
          if (x=y)
            t.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Pass message");
          else
            t.log(LogStatus.FAIL,"Fail message"+ screenshotMethod());

        objPage.Method2();
          if (a=b)
            t.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Pass message");
          else
            t.log(LogStatus.FAIL,"Fail message"+ screenshotMethod());

     } catch (Exception e) {
        t.log(LogStatus.ERROR, "Exception found: " + e.getMessage() + screenshotMethod());
    }
}
```

I am using PageFactory and ExtentReports. I am use `if` statements to report failures. No asserts. I believe if an assert fails, the result is the same, and the test ends.

Comment: method 1, 2 and 3 should all be their own unit tests , not bunched into a single tests. Also, why not use Assert , and then log the error in catch (Throwable t)...This way when test on method1 fails, method 2 and 3 will continue to execute...and your report will show 1 fails, 0 skipped ran 3 etc

Comment: Higher ups wanted no Asserts, for more customizable reports (I don't like it either). And I am using PageFactory, so method1, 2, 3, are simple parts of the overall workflow like entering an email and password. So they don't get their own @Tests. Just like not every Assert needs its own Test.

Comment: Then do a `try catch` around `Method1()`... what's the issue?

Comment: If you aren't going to use jUnit, etc. asserts, then at least write your own asserts that don't throw on error. The logging is unnecessarily verbose and will be a mess to maintain.

Comment: Right. The client wants detailed logs with test steps, so this is unfortunately what I'm working with now. There are many many action methods in the Page Object class. I could put a try/catch around each one, but then I'd be catching the exception in another class (where the current thread's extentreport instance is not active). I may be overthinking it, but it seems like there should be a way to simply HANDLE the exception (log it) and move on :(

Answer (score 0):

Write the objPage.Method2() in final block then it will execute.

Comment: I think this is a good answer for the example given. However, in my case I have many more than two methods. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @JeffC for pointing me in the right direction.

For my case, I have at least a dozen action methods called from the Page Object class. I can't put them all in their own final block.

What I did was put each workflow (one or more methods, then validation) in it's own try/catch. The catch includes logging/screenshot, then redirects to the page that the next workflow needs to execute. So, we try/catch(login), try/catch(enterHoursWorked) etc... As others have said, it's ugly, but in my case it works. Now the exception is added to the log, and the next workflow executes

```
    public void MyClientsFunctions() throws Exception {
    ExtentTest t = ReportFactory.getTest();
    try {

        Login objPage = new PageObject(driver);

        // this method throws exception
        try {
            objPage.Login();
            if (x = y)
                t.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Pass message");
            else
                t.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Fail message" + screenshotMethod());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            t.log(LogStatus.ERROR, "Exception found: " + e.getMessage() + screenshotMethod());
            objPage.BackToHomePage();
        }
        try {
            objPage.EnterHoursWorked();
            if (a = b)
                t.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Pass message");
            else
                t.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Fail message" + screenshotMethod());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            t.log(LogStatus.ERROR, "Exception found: " + e.getMessage() + screenshotMethod());
            objPage.BackToHomePage();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        t.log(LogStatus.ERROR, "Exception found: " + e.getMessage() + screenshotMethod());
    }
}
```